# List of quotes with ellipsis. Separate by commas?

Tags: punctuation, ellipses

I have this text:

> She is known for using phrases like. "Here will be…" "This place will be called…" "This wall will have this color…" She never starts her sentences with "I wish." She says, "That's how it will be," and so, it happens.

Is it correct, or there should be commans after each quote, for example like this?

> "Here will be…", "This place will be called…", "This wall will have this color…". She never starts her sentences with "I wish." She says, "That's how it will be," and so, it happens.

Also, before "She never starts", should there be a full stop?

Comment: She is known for using phrases like**:** "Here will be…"**;** "This place will be called…"**;** "This wall will have this color…"**, etc.**

Comment: thank you for your help

Comment: You first example is better. Just get the spacing in the ellipses right. The last one acts as the end of the sentence, in each case.